# How can a class have a function implementation but without its declaration?

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4, unreal-engine5

I am reading the following source code (taken from [this repository](https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Game-Development-Projects-with-Unreal-Engine/blob/79a987c01dd672b6e8b95bdd15f1d17380044bf8/Chapter16/Exercise16.03/Project/VariableReplication/Source/VariableReplication/VariableReplicationCharacter.cpp#L52)).

```
void AVariableReplicationCharacter::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(TArray< FLifetimeProperty >& OutLifetimeProps) const
{
    Super::GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(OutLifetimeProps);

    // Variable A doesn't have any additional replication condition 

    DOREPLIFETIME(AVariableReplicationCharacter, A);

    // Variable B should only replicate to the owner of this actor

    DOREPLIFETIME_CONDITION(AVariableReplicationCharacter, B, COND_OwnerOnly);
}
```

The function is implemented in `.cpp` but it has not corresponding declaration in `.h`. Surprisingly it can be compiled.

I attempted to replicate it with a simpler one as follows but it does not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class Parent
{
public:
    virtual void Job() const;
};

void Parent::Job() const
{
    cout << "Parent" << endl;
}

class Child : public Parent
{
public:
    virtual void Job() const override;
};

void Child::Job() const
{
    Parent::Job();
    cout << "Child" << endl;
}

class GrandChild : public Child
{
};

//= ATTEMPTING TO IMPLEMENT WITHOUT DECLARATION
void GrandChild::Job() const 
{
    Child::Job();
}

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    std::getchar();
}
```

#### Question

What C++ concept am I missing here?

Comment: Could it be that there are some MACROS defining the method?

Comment: Have you checked what the `UPROPERTY` macro does? For example, what does `UPROPERTY(Replicated)` expand to?

Comment: You can't. A declaration for the member function must be there inside the class definition in one form or another.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an accepted answer to this question, but it's vague and based on guessing, so I'll try to give a more definitive answer:

When declaring a class that can be replicated, it has to be defined as either an `AActor` or a `UActorComponent`. Both of which use the `UCLASS()` macro to denote that the following class declaration needs to be integrated into Unreals reflection using the Unreal Header Tool (UHT) which runs before the actual build and generates code. This code is written into a generated header file called "foo.generated.h" and code file called "foo.gen.cpp" where "foo" stands for your header filename (without extension). The header is always the last include in your header and exists once per header file, not per class.

Inside of the class, you also have to call the `GENERATED_BODY()` macro (or alternatively the `GENERATED_UCLASS_BODY()` macro, but I believe that's legacy stuff). That's where the code goes that's generated for the class itself by the UHT. It contains information about the `UPROPERTY()` and `UFUNCTION()` declarations and, if you are using the reflection on the class, also declares an override of `GetLifetimeReplicatedProps()` that you then have to implement.

This is not the only method that is declared by the UHT. If you are using RPCs, you also have to create an implementation to something you did not actually declare. A method declared as `Foo()` will have `Foo_Implementation()` as a body (because the implementation of the actual `Foo()` will be created via UHT, calling your implementation at some point) and optionally even a `Foo_Validate()`.

You can read more about this [here](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/rpcs-in-unreal-engine/).

Regarding the UHT, Unreals docs are [very vague](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/unreal-headr-tool-for-unreal-engine/), but I encourage you to look into its code [on their GitHub](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/tree/release/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealHeaderTool). Also, you can actually "go to declaration" of `GetLifetimeReplicatedProps()` after doing a compile. You should be able to view the generated code in the headers, they are located in the "Intermediate/Build" folders of your project.

Comment: Thank you. One more question, how do we know whether the declaration is optional or mandatory?

Comment: A declaration in and of itself is always mandatory. In all the years of using Unreal, the only times that I remember a declaration being done by the UHT is when the runtime needs to provide stuff to blueprints or networking. Another case other than those mentioned above can be when you have a [UFUNCTION(BlueprintNativeEvent)](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/function-specifiers/), because it allows you to provide a native implementation if it is not overridden by a Blueprint function.

Comment: I just found a case in which the author explicitly declare `GetLifetimeReplicatedProps()` as shown in section 2 and step 4 of [this tutorial](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/multiplayer-programming-quick-start-for-unreal-engine/).

Comment: As you can see [here](https://github.com/EpicGames/UnrealEngine/blob/release/Engine/Source/Programs/UnrealHeaderTool/Private/CodeGenerator.cpp#L292), the UHT checks if the the declaration exists and if it's missing, declares it in the generated header instead.

Answer (score 2):

> The function is implemented in .cpp but it has not corresponding declaration in .h.

A declaration for the member function must be there inside the class definition **in one form or another**.

Most likely, here the macro is used to indirectly write the declaration for the concerned member function. In any case, to be able to define a member function outside the class, a corresponding declaration for that particular member function must be there inside the class. Whether that declaration comes from macro is irrelevant.

Comment: And the declaration of function inside class is likely done via a function type declared beforehand and would look like a variable declaration, so  browsing through macroses might miss it

Comment: @Swift-FridayPie Yes, very likely.

Answer (score 0):

It is be because the `GENERATED_BODY()` macro automatically creates the declaration of `GetLifetimeReplicatedProps(TArray< FLifetimeProperty >& OutLifetimeProps) const` inside your `UCLASS()`. It does that only if it finds `UPROPERTY()` with the `Replicated` specifier and it leaves the implementation of that function to you.